# Why can't anonymous users delete files via ftp?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I've created a new directory "uploads" in `/var/ftp`. The owner and group of this directory is "ftp" and the permissions are set to 777.

Content of my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
anonymous_enable=YES

local_enable=YES    
write_enable=YES    
local_umask=022

anon_upload_enable=YES    
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES    
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog    
xferlog_std_format=YES

nopriv_user=ftpsecure

ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

SELINUX permissions are:

```
allow_ftpd_anon_write --> on
allow_ftpd_full_access --> on
```

I can upload files to the directory, but can't delete files through FTP.

Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: What happens when you try to delete them?  Do you see an error message?  Have you checked your ftp logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the following in `vsftp.conf`:-

```
anon_other_write_enable=YES
```

The man page says:-

```
If set to YES, anonymous users will be permitted to perform write operations
other than upload and create directory, such as deletion and renaming. This 
is generally not recommended but included for completeness.
```